# Triggering isotope relayout within content swapping js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have this simple content swapping script:

```
$(function(){

function contentSwitcher(settings){
    var settings = {
       contentClass : '.project-view',
       navigationId : '#projects-nav'
    };

    //Hide all of the content except the first one on the nav
    $(settings.contentClass).not(':first').hide();
    $(settings.navigationId).find('li:first').addClass('active');

    //onClick set the active state, 
    //hide the content panels and show the correct one
    $(settings.navigationId).find('a').click(function(e){
        var contentToShow = $(this).attr('href');
        contentToShow = $(contentToShow);

        //dissable normal link behaviour
        e.preventDefault();

        //set the proper active class for active state css
        $(settings.navigationId).find('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

        //hide the old content and show the new
        $(settings.contentClass).hide();
        contentToShow.show();

        $container.isotope('reLayout');

    });
}
contentSwitcher();
```

});

I'm trying to add a trigger for isotope relayout within it

```
$container.isotope('reLayout');
```

But I can't seem to get it to trigger. The initial tab loads fine but the 2nd one is all collapsed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of isotope are you using. Alternatively you could use the append method to add your items to your container : http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended

Answer (score 2):

A JSFiddle would help to troubleshoot. It looks like you may be using a deprecated Isotope function - new versions of Isotope change 'reLayout' option to 'layout'. Try changing

```
$container.isotope('reLayout');
```

... to ...

```
$container.isotope('layout');
```